# Getting Principal object in spring websocket controller

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, websocket

I have a troble with getting current logged in principal in spring with websockets.
Here is my configuration xml:

```
<websocket:message-broker>
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/ws">
        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

And here is my controller method, That works perfect without Principal parameter

```
@MessageMapping("/abc")
@SendTo("/showResult")
public String message(String message, Principal principal) {
    System.out.println("Principal " + principal.toString());
    return message;
}
```

Method with Principal parameter isn't being executed by spring. When I remove Principal it works perfect. Of course Spring Security works properly in e.g. rest controllers annotated with @RequestMapping

Comment: Did you take a look at that? http://javaninja.net/2014/01/getting-the-spring-security-principal-in-a-spring-mvc-controller-method/

Comment: @jny yes, but this is useful in normal http controller method. Here I using websockets and in this case it doesn't work

Comment: I tried to use SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.getUser(msg.getHeaders()) and It's return null, so I guess I have problem with spring security configration. Should I add something (like interceptor) to make it work?